# What is the right way to count records at different points in time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to determine what the right way to get a cumulative count of items for various points in time is, e.g.:

| Time window | Item Count |
| --- | --- |
| Days 0 - 1 | 4 |
| Days 0 - 2 | 6 |
| Days 0 - 3 | 7 |
| Days 0 - 4 | 12 |
| Days 0 - 5 | 15 |
| ... | ... |
| Days 0 - N | M |

I am not necessarily interested in starting from "0", but looking at the cumulative item count over the last 7, 30 or however many days.

The closest I've been able to come up with is something like this:

```
select * 
from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) as days (d)
left join lateral (
    select count(distinct item.id)
    from item
    where EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - item.creation_time) / 3600 / 24 >= days.d
) item_count on true;
```

I'm sure there is something in SQL, and more specifically Postgres, to do this much more efficiently. What SQL feature can help me with this?

Comment: Plz provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Your query looks fine except the condition: `where current_date- creation_time::date >= d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
  date_window.date_window,
  COUNT(item.creation_time)
FROM
  generate_series(0,30) AS date_window
LEFT JOIN item ON 
  date_part('day',NOW() - item.creation_time) <= date_window.date_window
GROUP BY 
  date_window.date_window
ORDER by 
  date_window.date_window
```

`generate_series` can be used to generate a sequence instead of manually typing and its size is the number of days you want to look back.

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/37bf6/1

Comment: This helped me get where I needed to be. Thanks so much!